# What makes Swift think that [String] is Int?

Tags: arrays, swift

I can write some short and valid example of code:

```
var array = ["one","two"];
var name = array[0];
```

All is ok. No errors. `name` now contains `one`.

Now suppose I write:

```
var array = ["one","two"];
var name = array["0"];
```

It *will* be a error, and its clear why: array is not a dictionary and I should access it contents by index.

But *why* does error say that "Type **`Int`** does not conform to protocol `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible`?

Why `Int`, if it is `[String]` ?

---

By the way, if I produce an error in another way

```
var array = ["one":0,"two":1];
var name = array[0];
```

It is clear: "type `DictionaryIndex<String, Int>` does not conform to protocol `IntegerLiteralConvertible`"

Comment: Because the array index is supposed to be a `String`, and passing a parameter of type `String` means (which conforms to `ExtendedWhatever` that long protocol name whatever it is) that it won't find the matching protocol conformance. You are right that the error message would probably be more intuitive if it worked the other way around (complaining about `String` not being conformant to something inherently `Int`-ish), but hey that's the way it's implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is because you are supplying a *string literal*, not an instance of the `String` type, where the compiler is expecting an `Int` (since that's what `Array`'s subscript method accepts). The way the compiler *would* convert a string literal to an instance of type `Int` is to use a method in the `StringLiteralConvertible` or `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible` protocols, so it checks to see if the `Int` type conforms to one of those. Since `Int` *doesn't* conform, you get the error message you're seeing.

This explains Daniel T's additional information:

```
var array = ["one","two"]
array["0"]                // trying to convert string literal to Int

var foo: Int = "0"        // trying to convert string literal to Int

var index = "0"
array[index]              // trying to convert String instance to Int
```

Likewise, your final example shows the compiler attempting the same thing—trying to convert an *integer literal* to an instance of `DictionaryIndex<String, Int>`, because a `Dictionary` instance's subscript can be passed either an instance of that dictionary's `Key` type *or* a `DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>`.

Answer (score 1):

`subscript` of `Array` declared as:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType, Sliceable {
    //... 
    subscript (index: Int) -> T
```

It expect `Int` as index. then if you do:

```
array["0"]
```

It's wrong, because `"0"` is not `Int`. But, in other words, if `"0"` can be `Int`, it will be OK.

Here, `"0"` is what in Swift? it's string, but actually it is `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral`. Swift has 2 string literal types, `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral` and `StringLiteral`.

- `""` empty → StringLiteral
- `"A"` just one character → ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral
- `"AB"` two or more characters → StringLiteral

Anyway, try this on Playground:

```
extension Int: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible {
    typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String
    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self = value.toInt() ?? 0
    }
    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self = value.toInt() ?? 0
    }
}

var array = ["one","two"];
var name = array["0"]; // -> "one"
```

"Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible'" means...

compiler: **"If `Int` conforms to `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible`, I can compile this!"**

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if you do this:

```
var array = ["one","two"];
var index = "0"
var name = array[index];
```

The error will be `'String' is not convertible to 'Int'`.

I think this happens because the system attempts to convert `"0"` into an Int which means doing a lot of protocol checks. Array's index type is convertible to Self.Index which is a ForwardIndexType... Well, things get weird.

Whereas Swift has strong rules against implicit variable type conversion. So if you use a variable as an index, it is more clear.

Note that `var foo: Int = "0"` produces the same error as your `array["0"]`.